# Case-insensitive GetMethod?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
foreach(var filter in filters)
{
    var filterType = typeof(Filters);
    var method = filterType.GetMethod(filter);
    if (method != null) value = (string)method.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
}
```

Is there a case-insensitive way to get a method?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, use BindingFlags.IgnoreCase:

```
var method = filterType.GetMethod(filter, 
    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Beware the possible ambiguity, you'd get an AmbiguousMatchException.

Comment: If there is an ambiguity, what will happen? Will it will just return the first one it finds?

Comment: @Logan: Thanks :) This is kind of strange though; if the only change I make to the above code is to add the `BindFlags` arg, my code stops working. `method` becomes null, even with BindingFlags.Default. What would cause it to stop matching *anything*?

Comment: It's actually static, but that fixes it. I'm a bit surprised `BindingFlags.Default` isn't the default binding.

Answer (score 5):

To get a method that acts like GetMethod(filter), except that it ignores the case you need:

```
var method = filterType.GetMethod(filter, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance| BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
```

This will not work:
    var method = filterType.GetMethod(filter, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this variant of [GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx), specifically note that one of the possible `BindingFlags` is `IgnoreCase`.