# Is possible to call a Method if I only have an String containing the method name?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Suppose that I've instanced an object like this:

```
Dim PerformPageSize as New HtmlToRtf.CPageStyle.CPageSize()
```

The Object contains some method members which I've put in an Enumeration like this, I mean, the enum strings are the same as the method names:

```
Friend Enum PageSize
    Auto
    A3
    A4
    A5
    A6
    Folio
    Letter
    Statement
End Enum
```

And I pass the Enum as parameter in a Method:

```
Friend Sub Test(Byval _pagesize as PageSize)
End Sub
```

Well, now my intention (to avoid writting a large Select case and do this efficientlly) is to parse the Enum value name to call the method (which have exactlly the same name)

So I would like to simplify this:

```
Friend Sub Test(Byval _pagesize as PageSize)

    Dim PerformPageSize As New HtmlToRtf.CPageStyle.CPageSize()

    Select Case PageSize

        Case PageSize.Auto
            PerformPageSize.Auto()

        Case PageSize.A3
            PerformPageSize.A3()

        Case PageSize.A4
            PerformPageSize.A4()

        Case PageSize.A5
            PerformPageSize.A5()

            ' Etc...

    End Select

End Sub
```

Into something like this else:

(I know that this code has no sense, but is just to understand the idea 'cause I don't know how should be a real solution using reflection or anything else):

```
Friend Sub Test(Byval _pagesize as PageSize)

    Dim PerformPageSize As New HtmlToRtf.CPageStyle.CPageSize()

    ' Parse the Enum value as the Method from the object
    Dim Method = PerformPageSize.TryPase(GetType(PageSize), _pagesize).ToString

    ' Call the equivalent method
    PerformPageSize.[Method]()

End Sub
```

Comment: That code is in C# but anyways I've tried to translate it to test it without success

Comment: A [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx) could be more appropriate. [Switch Statements Smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection like this:

```
Friend Sub Test(Byval _pagesize as PageSize)

    Dim performPageSize As New HtmlToRtf.CPageStyle.CPageSize()
    Dim pageType As Type = performPageSize.GetType()
    Dim method As MethodInfo = pageType.GetMethod(_pagesize.ToString())
    If Not method Is Nothing Then
        method.Invoke(performPageSize, Nothing)
    End If

End Sub
```

This should work as long as the methods are public. If not, you'll need to help out the `GetMethod()` method with a second parameter to specify the visibility of the method.

Comment: Thankyou so much, just a question to know for the future, the string should be case sensitive?

Comment: @ElektroStudios: IMO, yes, but if you want to ignore case, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4010017/74757